# IOError with Python Pdfkit

Tags: python, django, django-forms, pdfkit

I would like to generate a pdf when a user fills out a form with django and then save it onto my file system. It seems to work just file from the python shell. But when running it after a form is filled out, I get this error on the page:

IOError
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -6. error:
Loading pages (1/6)
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Unable to create thread pipe: Too many open files
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Can not continue without a thread pipe

Anyone have any idea what the issue is? The url I am downloading as a pdf is also on my server... could this be causing the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you open a lot of files at once, you need to set the max limit for your machine.

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

Do not forget to close the file object after you used it.

Comment: Hello Edwin, I don't think the issue is the number of files - it should only be one. It's just that my server, during the function is being asked to serve a second file to create the pdf. It works just fine if I use an external url. Do you know what the proper way is to work in this situation? Perhaps I need another thread?